# React Native Drawer Sidebar with subMenu. Is there a better approach?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I create a custom Drawer Navigator, like a submenu when the sidebar opens. This is the way i did it.
Each item has an index which is hardcoded. If you press on an item it sets the id to the index  `setId(index)` ,
once you press the subItem and you navigate to a page it resets the id,  `setId({})` . I did that so i can open and close the subitems.

Here are my screens:

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();



export const IncomingStack = () => {
  return (

    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={false} title={'Αρχική'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="DayViewCalendarMain"
          component={DayViewCalendarMain}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={true} title={'Ραντεβού: Mέρα'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="EventScreen"
          component={EventScreen}
          options={{
            headerShown: false
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="DayView"
          component={DayView}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={false} title={'Ραντεβού: Mέρα'} />
            ),
          }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="AppointmentsHistory"
          component={AppointmentsHistory}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={false} title={'Ραντεβού: Iστορικό'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="AddRantevou"
          component={AddRantevou}
          options={{

            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={true} title={'Προσθήκη Ραντεβού'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Διόρθωση ραντεβού"
          component={EditRantevou}
          options={{

            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={false} title={'Διόρθωση ραντεβού'} />
            ),
          }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="Calendar"
          component={CalendarMonth}
          options={{

            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={false} title={'Μήνας'} />
            ),
          }}
        />

      </Stack.Group>
      <Stack.Group>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="IncomingCallsForm"
          component={IncomingCallsForm}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={false} title={'Κλήσεις'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="IncomingCalls"
          component={IncomingCalls}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={true} title={'Κλήσεις'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="IncomingEmailForm"
          component={IncomingEmailForm}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={false} title={'Email'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="IncomingEmails"
          component={IncomingEmails}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={true} title={'Email'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="IncomingEltaForm"
          component={IncomingEltaForm}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={false} title={'Ελτά'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="IncomingElta"
          component={IncomingElta}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={true} title={'Ελτά'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="IncomingTaskForm"
          component={IncomingTaskForm}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={false} title={'Αναφορά εργασίας'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="IncomingTasks"
          component={IncomingTasks}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={true} title={'Αναφορά εργασίας'} />
            ),
          }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="CustomerSearchForm"
          component={CustomerSearchForm}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={false} title={'Πελάτες'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Πελάτες"
          component={Customers}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={true} title={'Πελάτες'} />
            ),
          }}
        />

        <Stack.Screen
          name="Προσθήκη πελάτη"
          component={AddCustomer}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={true} title={'Προσθήκη Πελάτη'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Διόρθωση πελάτη"
          component={EditCustomer}
          options={{
            header: ({ navigation }) => (
              <NavStyle navigation={navigation} showback={true} title={'Διόρθωση πελάτη'} />
            ),
          }}
        />
      </Stack.Group>


    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

and here is the custom drawer navigator

```
const CustomDrawer = (props) => {
  const [id, setId] = useState({})


  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props} >
      <View style={styles.headerView}>
        <BoldText style={{ fontSize: 28, color: COLORS.contrastText }}>MyOffice Services</BoldText>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 17, color: COLORS.secondaryColor }}>WE SIMPLIFY YOUR WORK LIFE</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DrawerItem title="Αρχική" Icon={Entypo} iconName="home" index={4} id={id} setId={setId} homePage={true} />

      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DrawerItem title="Ραντεβού" Icon={Entypo} iconName="calendar" index={1} id={id} setId={setId} />
        {id == 1 && (
          <DrawerSubItemView >
            <DrawerSubItem title="Μήνας" screen="Calendar" setId={setId} show={true} />
            <DrawerSubItem title="Μέρα Λίστα" parent="Ραντεβού" screen="DayView" setId={setId} />
            <DrawerSubItem title="Ιστορικό" screen="AppointmentsHistory" setId={setId} />
          </DrawerSubItemView>
        )}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DrawerItem title="Εισερχόμενα" Icon={Material} iconName="call-received" index={2} id={id} setId={setId} />
        {id == 2 && (
          <DrawerSubItemView>
            <DrawerSubItem title="Κλήσεις" screen="IncomingCallsForm" setId={setId} />
            <DrawerSubItem title="Email" screen="IncomingEmailForm" setId={setId} />
            <DrawerSubItem title="Εlta" screen="IncomingEltaForm" setId={setId} />
            <DrawerSubItem title="Αναφορά Εργασίας" screen="IncomingTaskForm" setId={setId} />
          </DrawerSubItemView>
        )}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <DrawerItem title="Πελάτες" Icon={Ion} iconName="person" index={3} id={id} setId={setId} />
        {id == 3 && (
          <DrawerSubItemView>
            <DrawerSubItem title="Πελάτες" screen="CustomerSearchForm" setId={setId} />
            <DrawerSubItem title="Προσθήκη Πελάτη" screen="Προσθήκη πελάτη" setId={setId} />
          </DrawerSubItemView>
        )}
      </View>
    </DrawerContentScrollView >
  )

}


const DrawerItem = ({ title, Icon, iconName, index, setId, id, homePage }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const handleCollapse = () => {
    if (index == id) {
      setId({})
    } else {
      setId(index)
    }

  }

  const goToHome = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Home')
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.sidebarItem} onPress={homePage ? goToHome : handleCollapse} >
      <View style={styles.iconView}>
        <Icon style={styles.subIcon} name={iconName} size={13} color="white" />
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.itemText} >{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}

const DrawerSubItemView = ({ children }) => {
  const fadeAnim = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current; // Initial value for opacity: 0

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(fadeAnim, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, [fadeAnim]);

  return (

    <Animated.View
      style={[{ opacity: fadeAnim }, styles.subItemView]}>
      {children}
    </Animated.View>
  )
}


const DrawerSubItem = ({ screen, title, setId, date, show, dateBool }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  // const { setDay } = useContext(DayContext)
  const onPress = () => {

    setId({})
    navigation.navigate(screen, { date: date, show: show })

  }
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.subItem} onPress={onPress} >
      <View style={styles.subItemLeftView}></View>
      <Text style={styles.itemText}>{title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}


export default CustomDrawer;
```

Is this a good practice? Is there a better way I could approach the problem?

Answer (score 1):

### There are 03 ways you can use to do this task.

1. **Using a nested drawer navigator**:
   You can use the `@react-navigation/drawer` package to implement a nested drawer navigator, where each menu item in the parent drawer opens up a new drawer with its own submenu items. This approach can be useful if you have a large number of menu items and submenus, as it can help keep the UI organized and easy to navigate.

---

2. **Creating your own custom sidebar component**:
   This has *more flexibility*. And this will *take more time* to do this task.

---

3. **Use a third-party library**: `react-native-side-drawer-menu` and `react-native-drawer-menu` packages are two examples of this kind of library. These libraries can save you development time, but may not provide as much flexibility as creating a custom component.

---

These are the ways you can use. Depending on your project requirement your approach will be defer.